# Random variable corresponding to sum of density functions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

The distribution of functions of random variables is well-studied for various different and general cases, but I didn't find much result for the reverse.

> Suppose that $X_1, X_2$ are (probably independent) random variables and we have $X_1\sim f(x_1)$ and $X_2\sim g(x_2)$. Construct a new distribution for the new random variable $X$ as follows:
>   $$X\sim p(x)=\frac{1}{\kappa}(f(x)+g(x))$$
>   where $\kappa$ is a normalization factor such that the function is a density function. 
>   Is it possible to express $X$ as a function of $X_1$ and $X_2$ in a way that their PDF is $p(x)$?
>
> More formally, find a function $G$ such that 
>   $$X=G(X_1, X_2)\sim p(x)$$

Note: "$\sim$" denotes the probability density function of a random variable.

Note 2: If we had $p(x)=f(x)*g(x)$, where $*$ is the sign for convolution, then I think we may write $G(X_1, X_2) = X_1+X_2$.

Note 3: I have asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3588454/255648) for product of density functions.

Comment: This is not really a research level question; I'm voting to migrate to http://math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $X_1 \sim f(x_1)$ means that that the distribution of $X_1$ has density function $f$.

Note first that your $\kappa$ can only be $2$, otherwise the integral of $p$ will not equal $1$.  Then $p$ is the density of a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of $X_1, X_2$; it corresponds to flipping a coin to decide whether to take $X_1$ or $X_2$. In notation, if $A$ is an event of probability $1/2$ that is independent of $(X_1, X_2)$, then $p$ is the density of the random variable $X = 1_A X_1 + 1_{A^c} X_2$.  You can also think of it as $X = Z X_1+ (1-Z) X_2$ where $Z$ is a Bernoulli(1/2) random variable independent of $(X_1, X_2)$.

In general such a random variable cannot be written as a function of $X_1, X_2$ alone.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So, it is not possible to write $1_A$ in terms of $(X_1, X_2)$?

Comment: @SMA.D: No, because as I said, $A$ must be independent of $(X_1, X_2)$.  If it could be written as a function of $(X_1, X_2)$, it would be independent of itself and therefore could only have probability 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize X to the standard deviation  of the underlying population  and input that as p(x). This will allow X to be used as an input to a probability density function regardless of it's original distribution.